# JavaScript Access random input value inside class

Tags: javascript, class, search, token

I have a webpage and I am trying to render the response of it.
I am interested in getting the value of the a random Token that's assigned to the User.
for example the response contains:

```
<input type='hidden' name='TOKEN236030854X1539105004' value='sqpxefsQf1LbdAZvyy9GmUEUU8Uz/8o7' class='_post_token' />
```

I did search for the class first:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_post_token');
```

then extract the value of the TOKEN:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_post_token').TOKEN515634759X1539104492.value;
```

How can I search for the TOKEN ? because the application is appending random value to the work TOKEN.
is there a way to search with wildcard like TOKEN* ? or anything to help me in getting to the parameter and extract the value ?

Regards,

Comment: There is a pseudo selector for attributes values, `starts with`, so you could do `document.querySelector("input[name^='TOKEN']").value` to find the token value for an input whose name starts with "TOKEN".

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should do the trick:

```
document.querySelector('._post_token').value
```

Comment: Can you illustrate why you have to place . in-front of _post_token ?

Comment: @FahadK. because it's a query for querySelector. Selector rules are the same as for CSS, so if you will pass it without a dot, it will be looking for a tag with this name instead of class

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` is in plural form, indicating that it returns many elements. As such, you could:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('_post_token')[0]; // Gets first element, which is at index 0
```

Then I'm, not sure whether you want the name or the value of the token:

```
var name = element.name;
var value = element.value;

console.log(name);
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the input's name starts with "TOKEN", you could find the input using the "starts with" wildcard syntax:

```
var tokenValue = document.querySelector("input[name^='TOKEN']").value;
```

The selector passed to `document.querySelector` finds the first `<input>` field whose `name` *starts with* "TOKEN" and returns its value.

```js
var tokenValue = document.querySelector("input[name^='TOKEN']").value;

console.log(tokenValue);
```

```html
<input type='hidden' name='TOKEN236030854X1539105004' value='sqpxefsQf1LbdAZvyy9GmUEUU8Uz/8o7' class='_post_token' />
```

Comment: Thanks! for more general cases this is better